# Show text after existing text with interval

Tags: javascript, html

Zup Stackoverflow!
I have a question regarding a problem I can't seem to solve. I want to add text with a intervalfunction which should only be seen after the already existing text inside a h2 tag. The data comes from the list array. So something like this:

HTML:

```
<div id="output">
    <h2 id="funny-day">Funny day: (HERE IS WHERE I WANT THE OUTPUT TO BE)</h2>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
//Get elements
var funny-day = document.getElementById("funny-day");

//Array
var list = ["Sunny", "Cloudy", "Rainy"]

//Function to output array
var index = 0;
markiser.innerHTML = markiser.textContent;
setInterval(function() { 

    var text = (list[index++ % list.length]).toString();
    markiser.innerHTML += text; <<Not working ofcourse since it only appends 

}, 2000);
```

Important note is that I want to keep the "Funny day: " inside the h2 tag because of SEO purposes.

Comment: What is a `markiser` ? And javascript does not allow to have variables named with minus inside

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you add a tag specificly for your data like `<span class="data">yourdata</span>`

```js
//Get elements
var funnyDay = document.getElementById("funny-day");

//Array
var list = ["Sunny", "Cloudy", "Rainy"]

//Function to output array
var index = 0;
setInterval(function() { 

    var text = (list[index++ % list.length]).toString();
   document.getElementById("data").innerHTML = text 

}, 2000);
```

```html
<div id="output">
    <h2 id="funny-day">Funny day: <span id="data" >(HERE IS WHERE I WANT THE OUTPUT TO BE)</span></h2>
</div>
```

I edited a few things that made no sense, for example your function cannot have `-` in it, Also, your `markiser` was not defined in the scope.

Comment: Awesome thanks alot, worked like a charm! "Markise"r is a swedish word, I forgot to replace it with f"unny-day". I didn't want to confuse you guys with a foreign language in the code. The "-" was something that I problaby added by mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```js
//Get elements
var funnyday = document.getElementById("funny-day");

//Array
var list = ["Sunny", "Cloudy", "Rainy"];

//Function to output array
var index = 0;

funnyday.innerHTML = ("Funny day: " + list[index]);
index=index >= list.length - 1 ? 0 : index+1;
setInterval(function() { 
  funnyday.innerHTML = ("Funny day: " + list[index]);
  index=index >= list.length - 1 ? 0 : index+1;
}, 2000);
```

```html
<div id="output">
    <h2 id="funny-day">Funny day: </h2>
</div>
```